# Fetching data in class component in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to use the search api of [Open Library](https://openlibrary.org/developers/api).

Usually, if you are going to use a functional component, you will do it like this on your api file:

```
import axios from 'axios';
export default axios.create({
    baseuRL: 'http://openlibrary.org/search.json'
})
```

And then you will import this on a file where you will fetch the data:

```
import booksAPI from '../apis/books';

const books = () => {

useEffect(() => {
    books()
}, [])

    const books = async() => {
        const res =  await booksAPI.get('?author=tolkien');
        console.log(res.data);
    }
}
```

This is expected to console.log the data on your terminal. However, using the class component with `axios` and `componentDidMount` to fetch the data.

```
class BookList extends Component {
    
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      books: []
    }
  }

    componentDidMount(){
        const booksResponse = async() => {
            const response = await booksAPI.get('?author=tolkien');
            console.log(response.data)
        } 
    }
```

This is complaining about the `await` keyword and doesn't console.log the data. Also, I am not sure how I can convert the `useEffect` to a class component so it can perform side effects?

Comment: I don't see you call `booksResponse `

Comment: Can I call it inside componentDidMount?

Comment: Yes, Call it after you decalre and inside `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const BookList = () => {
  // State variable where you can store the data
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);

  // Effect, which would be called on component mount because of empty array of dependencies -> [] (look for useEffect lifecycles) and set the data to state variable. After this, component will re-render.
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchBooks = async () => {
        const response = await booksAPI.get('?author=tolkien');
        setBooks(response.data);
        console.log(response.data);
    }

    fetchBooks();
  }, []);


  return ...
}
```

Also, make sure that you're adding `query`/`mutation`/`subscription` to your GraphQL document right before the name of query/mutation/subscription, as someones told you in the comment.

In case you're looking for class component realization, your code should look like this:

```
class BookList extends Component {
    
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      books: []
    }
  }

  fetchBooks = () => {
    const response = booksAPI.get('?author=tolkien');
    this.setState({ books: response.data });
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    fetchBooks();
  }

  ...

}
```

Comment: Really helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here I have created a simple example in React for you.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.booksResponse();
 }
 booksResponse = async () => {
   const response = await axios.get(
      'https://openlibrary.org/search.json?author=token'
 );
 console.log(response.data);
 };
```

Here is Stackblitz link.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zk8nhq

If you find any confusing then Please comment here I can create more example for you.